# Bash call variables in for loop variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am curious to know that whether it is possible in bash that we can run for loop on a bunch of variables and call those values within for loop. Example:

```
a="hello"
b="world"
c="this is bash"

for f in a b c; do {
  echo $( $f )
OR
  echo $ ( "$f" )
} done
```

I know this is not working but can we call the values saved in a, b and c variables in for loop with printing f. I tried multiple way but unable to resolve.

Comment: Instead `for f in $a $b $c` and `echo $f`

Comment: Thank you @JNevil. It's so easy. Unnecessary, I was trying hard.

Comment: to avoid splitting on white space make sure you double quote your variable references, eg, `for f in "$a" "$b" "$c"` and `echo "$f"`

Comment: what do you mean by "call those values"? execute the command named by the value of the variable?

Comment: @PiyushkumarPatel : What does it mean to **call** a variable, respectively to **call** a value?

Answer (score 3):

You need the `!` like this:

```
for f in a b c; do
  echo "${!f}"
done
```

Comment: Now I'm confused as to whether the OP wanted a direct or an indirect variable.   Well, it's educational either way...

Comment: @agc : Actually I find the question confusing. I have no idea what the OP wants to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `nameref`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a="hello"
b="world"
c="this is bash"

declare -n f
for f in a b c; do 
  printf "%s\n" "$f"
done
```

From [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html):

> If the control variable in a for loop has the nameref attribute, the list of words can be a list of shell variables, and a name reference will be established for each word in the list, in turn, when the loop is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Notes on the OP's code, (scroll to bottom for corrected version):

```
for f in a b c; do {
  echo $( $f )
} done
```

Problems:

1. The purpose of `{` & `}` is usually to put the separate outputs of
   separate unpiped commands into one stream.  Example of separate
   commands:

   ```
   echo foo; echo bar | tac
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   foo
   bar
   ```

   The `tac` command puts lines of input in reverse order, but in the
   code above it only gets **one** line, so there's nothing to reverse.
   But with curly braces:

   ```
   { echo foo; echo bar; } | tac
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   bar
   foo
   ```

   A `do ... done` already acts just like curly braces.
   So "`do {`" instead of a "`do`" is unnecessary and redundant; but it
   won't harm anything, or have any effect.
2. If `f=hello` and we write:

   ```
   echo $f
   ```

   The output will be:

   ```
   hello
   ```

   But the code `$( $f )` runs a subshell on `$f` which only works if `$f` is
   a command.  So:

   ```
   echo $( $f )
   ```

   ...tries to run the command `hello`, but there probably is no such
   command, so the subshell will output to standard error:

   ```
   hello: command not found
   ```

   ...but no data is sent to standard  output, so `echo` will
   print nothing.

---

To fix:

```
a="hello"
b="world"
c="this is bash"

for f in "$a" "$b" "$c"; do
  echo "$f"
done
```